# number not callable in jquery each

Tags: javascript, jquery

I sometimes get a weird exception in jquerys "each" implementation (at least in 2.1.0 and 2.1.1)
"Type error: number is not callable" (currently in core.js 314)

The problem is, that it only occurs on Chrome on Windows (not in Chrome OSX or Firefox on Windows) when run with the Developer Tools closed.

Another part of the problem is, that it only occurs in a complicate sequence of events which include opening the the window, doing some AJAX calls in building a complicated DOM in which the exception occurs.

The JavaScript console does not show a callstack after the exception. The only case I have seen with a breakpoint showed a MouseEvent on the top of the stack, lots of jquery code and some anonymuos functions in jquery.

Any ideas?

Changing jquery to ignore the exception(try / catch)  would solves the problem for me, but why would take that change upstream

Comment: Can you please post your code?

Comment: Don't think this is debuggable from the current description. You're going to need a reproducible case before you can get any reasonable answer.

Comment: No I can't, it 3.6 MB of code....

Comment: @nrabinowitz: How do I produce one without debugger?

Comment: @RuedigerJungbeck Right before the line that errors, you could put an `if` statement that tests for the "bad condition" (presumably that something being executed as a function is actually, and erroneously for some reason, of type `Number` instead of `Function`, according to your question title). Within the `if` statement body, you could then put `alert` statements that alert with various values that you would like to inspect at that point in execution. This is effectively a poor-man's debugger without the dev tools.